# Server authentication via PHP session

Tags: javascript, c#, php, authentication, websocket

I have a little question about possibilities to change authentication on my C# server from Login\Password to PHP session. I am using PHP, HTML5, and JavaScript as client side, and C# server with WebSockets lib as server side. I already have authorization code, but it works only with login and password.

Well, I have the same authentication code, that checks login & password via PHP. But how I can authorize client on C# server, by using WebSockets with PHP session, instead account login & password?

Little pic:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is this possible? And any piece of code, demo, etc. for it?

Comment: You can generate token in php like `md5(time())` save it in database and read token from database in C# then you can save all stored in session in database. then you can store the token in a cookie or in localStorage. You will have your own session mechanizm.

Answer (score 2):

Genreate an access token that your c# server can validate. This is how i would implement it:

share a secret between your PHP and C# server (e.g. 64 randcom bytes)

When PHP validates the user/login, generate a token: it contains random characters, the user ID and a signature that was created using the shared secret. E.g. something like this:

```
$random = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
$token = $random . '_' . $userID . '_' . hash_hmac('sha256', $random . '_' . $userID, SHARED_SECRET);
```

The C# server can then verify this token by calcuating the HMAC signature from $random and $token with the shared secret. If correct, the C# server can work with the $userID and the MySQL databse.

As long as you pass the token to your JS code via https, you should be secure.

P.S.: You can improve the security of this scheme by adding an expiration date to the token and make your JS code request a new token in time. Dont forget to include the expiry in the signature.